# How can I access OneDrive?

Tags: cloud

I want to make my Linux PC part of my existing digital world, which includes current documents that I share between Windows 10 and iOS devices using MicroSoft OneDrive.  Can I access my OneDrive from Ubuntu Linux?

Answer (score 1):

I am the developer of the Linux OneDrive Client:

- https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive

For Ubuntu platforms, either use the Ubuntu PPA or build from source.

Any issues, or questions, post a query on GitHub

Comment: Apologies, I didn't see Linux as an officially supported OS and assumed there was no such client.